# Selenium headless chrome with proxy authentication

Tags: c#, selenium, proxy, selenium-chromedriver, headless

I'm working on automation of Headless Chrome WebDriver (100.0.48.96.60) using Selenium (4.1.0) and C# (.Net 5.0/Console application). I want to add Proxy Authentication, but nothing seems to work for me.

What I've tried so far:

1. Selenium's BiDi API: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/bidirectional/bidi_api/#register-basic-auth It's causing 2 exceptions at random times (possibly when opening a url):

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A command response was not received: Fetch.getResponseBody'

> OpenQA.Selenium.DevTools.CommandResponseException: 'Fetch.continueRequest: Invalid InterceptionId.'

2. Proxy Auth Extension: https://github.com/RDavydenko/OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriverExtensions. It doesn't work with headless chrome.
3. AutoIT. Also doesn't work in headless chrome I think.
4. Setting proxy like so:

> "username:password@IP:PORT"

All the answers I could find are either not working for headless or just not working anymore. So fell free to leave any idea you can think of about that subject.

Answer (score 0):

This response is in Java but im sur you can adapt it to C# which have both libraries,
Its using Augmenter with BI-DI of selenium its works for me in headless (https://www.browserstack.com/docs/automate/selenium/event-driven-testing#register-basic-auth).

You have 4 var to fill PROXY_HOST,PROXY_PORT,PROXY_USER,PROXY_PASS:

```
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.setHeadless(true);
    options.setProxy(new Proxy().setHttpProxy(PROXY_HOST + ":" + PROXY_PORT).setSslProxy(PROXY_HOST + ":" + PROXY_PORT));
    driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    DevTools devTools = ((HasDevTools) driver).getDevTools();
    devTools.createSession();
    driver = new Augmenter().
            addDriverAugmentation("chrome", HasAuthentication.class, (caps, exec) -> (whenThisMatches, useTheseCredentials) -> devTools.getDomains().network().addAuthHandler(whenThisMatches, useTheseCredentials)).augment(driver);
    ((HasAuthentication) driver).register(UsernameAndPassword.of(PROXY_USER, PROXY_PASS));
```